# Regex pattern matching using @Pattern annotation in Spring Boot

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-boot

**I want to accept only those titles which don't contain following characters: \/:*?"<>|**

I tried using the below method, but it didn't work for me

```
@Pattern(regexp = "[^\\/:*?\"<>|]", message = "Not valid")
private String title;
```

I am new in pattern matching so please help me with the solution...

Comment: Did you get an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good start. The [`@Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) annotation defines the pattern the underlying String should match.

> The annotated CharSequence must match the specified regular expression. The regular expression follows the Java regular expression conventions see [Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html?is-external=true).

In your case, you only list the characters, that should not be matched. You should define a pattern to be matched instead.

Try this one (see [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/XOSawc/1) for a demo) and notice the `+` quantifier.

```
^[^\/:*?\"<>|]+$
```

In Java, mind the escaping:

```java
@Pattern(regexp = "^[^\\/:*?\\\"<>|]+$", message = "Not valid")
private String title;
```

Comment: thanks for your help. It's working now. But can you tell me reason we're using $ and also ^ before the square bracket.

Comment: It's optional and not mandatory to use in this case.